# Bootstrap Navwalker not displaying

Tags: navigation, walker, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a bootstrap wordpress theme from scratch, i want to create a nav menu using WordPress nav walker class, i followed the documentation on [GitHub](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker) to install it, then i added a primary menu to my wordpress theme, i chose the menu location but the navbar won't display, all i have is the navbar brand going in the center.
[image] 
my header.php code:

```
<div class="blog-masthead">
      <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
                <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
            </a>
    </div>

        <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'primary',
                'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                'depth'             => 2,
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker())
            );
        ?>
    </div>
</nav>

      </div>
    </div>
```

functions.php

```
<?php
    require_once('wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php');

    function wpb_theme_setup(){
        register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'wpbootstrap' ),
) );
    }

    add_action('after_setup_theme', 'wpb_theme_setup');
```

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: try my version, I modified it to work woth current versions of WP
https://github.com/jaycbrf4/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

Answer (score 1):

I use it this way. I have never encountered any problems.

Bootstrap 3.x Navigation with dropdown for wordpress.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs" href="#">MENU</a>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse">
    <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location'    => 'primary',
            'depth'             => 2,
            'container'         => '',
            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
        );
    ?>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> HESABIM <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <?php foreach ( wc_get_account_menu_items() as $endpoint => $label ) : ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_account_endpoint_url( $endpoint ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $label ); ?></a></li>                             
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ); ?>" title="Üye Ol / Giriş Yap">Üye Ol / Giriş Yap</a></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Navigation Only;

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse">
<?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location'    => 'primary',
        'depth'             => 2,
        'container'         => '',
        'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
        'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
        'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
    );
?>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this it worked for me but it's showing me just the links without style even though i adde the class

Comment: Edited my answer.